# Crystal Reports Viewer Component - Royalty Free?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Does anyone know if the Crystal Reports Viewer that comes with Visual Studio 2008 is a royalty free distribution for C# apps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the [license agreement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288179(VS.71).aspx) says:

> USE AND DISTRIBUTION OF RUNTIME
>   SOFTWARE.
>   4.1   Deployment and Distribution of Client Applications. Crystal Decisions
>   grants you a personal, nonexclusive,
>   limited license to deploy, reproduce
>   and distribute Client Applications to
>   end users, if you comply with all of
>   the terms of this license agreement,
>   including section 4.4.
>
> 4.2   Deployment Within Your Organization of Server/Web
>   Applications. After you have activated
>   your copy of the Software, you may
>   install and use Server/Web
>   Applications in one or more Server
>   Environments owned or operated by you
>   for your internal business purposes.
>   You may not use the Software or a
>   Server/Web Application on a rental or
>   timesharing basis or to operate a
>   service bureau facility for the
>   benefit of third-parties unless you
>   first acquire an Application Service
>   Provider License from Crystal
>   Decisions. The Runtime Software may be
>   installed on only one server in each
>   Server Environment, and only one
>   instance of the Runtime Software per
>   Server/Web Application may be utilized
>   on that Server at any one time. While
>   you may allow Access to the Runtime
>   Software by an unlimited number of
>   users, the version of the Runtime
>   Software provided with Visual Studio
>   .NET is a performance limited edition
>   intended for development purposes and
>   use with Server/Web Applications
>   accessed by small groups. If multiple
>   users are simultaneously accessing the
>   Runtime Software, performance will be
>   affected and users may be unable to
>   access the Runtime Software. If you
>   want to deploy the Runtime Software in
>   a production environment or extend the
>   performance of the version of the
>   Runtime Software provided with Visual
>   Studio .NET, you may purchase
>   additional licensing from Crystal
>   Decisions as a stand-alone offering.
>   For more information, please visit the
>   Crystal Decisions' Web site at
>   http://www.crystaldecisions.com/net/licensing.
>
> 4.3   Distribution to Third Parties of Server/Web Applications. This license
>   agreement does not in itself give you
>   any right to distribute Server/Web
>   Applications to third parties. If you
>   want to distribute Server/Web
>   Applications to third parties, you
>   must obtain written authorization from
>   Crystal Decisions to do so. If you
>   obtain written authorization from
>   Crystal Decisions to distribute
>   Server/Web Applications to third
>   parties, you may reproduce and
>   distribute copies of Server/Web
>   Applications to end users of
>   Server/Web Applications so long as you
>   comply with all of the terms of this
>   license agreement, including section
>   4.4. For more information, please visit the Crystal Decisions' Web site
>   at
>   http://www.crystaldecisions.com/net/licensing.
>
> 4.4   Runtime Software Distribution Requirements. If you distribute the
>   Runtime Software to Third Parties
>   pursuant to sections 4.1 or 4.3, you
>   agree to comply with the following
>   requirements:
>
> 4.4.1   You distribute copies of the Runtime Software solely as a part of
>   specific-purpose application programs
>   written using an authorized copy of
>   the Software;
>
> 4.4.2   You remain solely responsible for support, service, upgrades, and
>   technical or other assistance,
>   required or requested by anyone
>   receiving such Runtime Software copies
>   or sample applications;
>
> 4.4.3   You do not use the name, logo, or trademark of Crystal Decisions, or
>   the Software, without written
>   permission from Crystal Decisions;
>
> 4.4.4   You do not alter, disassemble, decompile, translate, adapt or
>   reverse-engineer the Runtime Software;
>
> 4.4.5   You do not alter, disassemble, decompile, translate, adapt,
>   reverse-engineer, or convert the
>   report file (.RPT) format to an
>   alternative format, including but not
>   limited to report file formats of
>   general purpose report writer or
>   database querying products that are
>   not property of Crystal Decisions,
>   except as permitted by the Software,
>   without written permission from
>   Crystal Decisions;
>
> 4.4.6   You do not use the Client Application or the Server/Web
>   Application on a rental or timesharing
>   basis or to operate a service bureau
>   facility for the benefit of
>   third-parties unless you first acquire
>   an Application Service Provider
>   License from Crystal Decisions.
>
> 4.4.7   You will defend, indemnify and hold Crystal Decisions harmless
>   against any claims or liabilities
>   arising out of the use, reproduction
>   or distribution of Runtime Software;
>
> 4.4.8   You shall secure the end user's consent to terms substantially
>   similar to the following:
>
> End User agrees not to alter,
>   disassemble, decompile, translate,
>   adapt or reverse-engineer the Runtime
>   Software or the report file (.RPT)
>   format;
>
> End User agrees not to use, distribute
>   or integrate the Runtime Software with
>   any general-purpose report writing or
>   report delivery product that is
>   generally competitive with Crystal
>   Decisions product offerings;
>
> End User agrees not to use the
>   Software on a rental or timesharing
>   basis or to operate a service bureau
>   facility for the benefit of
>   third-parties unless End User first
>   acquires an Application Service
>   Provider License from Crystal
>   Decisions;
>
> End User may not use the Software or
>   Runtime Software, together or
>   separately or in combination with
>   Server Environments, as part of a
>   Report Distribution System, without
>   obtaining an additional license from
>   Crystal Decisions;

So it really depends on the type of application you are doing. A "specific purpose" client application is royalty-free, but a server/web application may not be.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to double-check the EULA, but I'm pretty certain the one that's part of the .NET library is, indeed, royalty free.  BTW - it is not *exactly* the same version you'd get if went and actually bought a version of Crystal Reports.  They sometimes (as in, every time I've seen someone try) have issues if you want to integrate the two.